# Chart Js , loading data on selection but bar graph displaying old values as well on hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am trying to dynamically update the chart. I have got different values from the database via another js  for name (#cellname) also there is cellname and throughput against each other in data.php (which is being called by ajax).

Whenever new selection is made the below script is running fine except when i move mouse on the graph it displays old graph as well, somehow i am lacking to use the chart update function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function load_stats(id) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost/visx/data.php",
      method: "GET",
      data: {
        id: id
      },
      dataType: "JSON",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        // variable declaration
        var date = [];
        var cellname = [];
        var throughputs = [];

        // Store database values to Variables
        for (var i in data) {
          date.push(data[i].starttime);
          cellname.push(data[i].cellname);
          throughputs.push(data[i].thrp_bits_dl);    
        }

        // Creating Chart
        var ctx = document.getElementById('VF_Requests').getContext('2d');
        var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'bar',
          data: {
            labels: date,
            datasets: [{
              // label:,
              backgroundColor: 'rgb(174,199,232)',
              data: throughputs,
            }]
          },
        });
      },
    });
  }

  // load function
  $('#cellname').click(function() {
    var id = $('#cellname option:selected').val();
    if (id != '') {
      load_stats(id);
    } else {

    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the old chart is still present in the `canvas`. Instead of creating a new chart each time new data is available, you should simply assign the new values to `labels` and the `dataset` and then [update the existing chart](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html).

To do so, you'll define a global variable `chart` and change your code as follows:

```
var chart;
function load_stats(id) {
  $.ajax({
      ...

      if (chart) {
        // Updating Chart
        chart.data.labels = date;
        chart.data.datasets[0].data = throughputs;  
        chart.update();
      } else {
        // Creating Chart
        chart = new Chart('VF_Requests', {
          type: 'bar',
          data: {
            labels: date,
            datasets: [{
              backgroundColor: 'rgb(174,199,232)',
              data: throughputs
            }]
          }
        });
      }
    },
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks uminder, I was trying to solve it past 24hrs, You are a life save. God bless you man . Thanks

Comment: @Ali: Glad I could help. Please consider marking my answer as accepted if you think it was the solution to your question (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251399/2358409)