# chartjs line graph destroy function is not clearing the old chart instances

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

note1: excuse me about my code as i am a beginner. i also welcome any criticism to my code.
note2: i have not included the code part that populates the select tag for simplicity.

i have Select tag which returns different customer names as variable x, which i am using to get the customer specific data from Solarwinds and charting it.

everything works fine except that when i switch to other customer, if i hover my mouse on the chart, the previous charts appear.

i tried using chart.destroy() just before drawing the chart, inside the function but before ajax, after the chart etc.. but it just doesnt fit anywhere and not clearing it. i spent more than a week on this.

```
<script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script>
     function getoptiontunnels()
     {
     
        var x = document.getElementById("Choosecustomer").value
        var swql_vpn="select tbl.datetime, sum(tbl.rawstatus) as tunnels, substring (cpa.assignmentname, Charindex ('arvpn', cpa.assignmentname) , 30) AS node FROM (SELECT CustomPollerAssignmentID, DateTime, RawStatus FROM Orion.NPM.CustomPollerStatistics cps join orion.NPM.CustomPollerLabels cpl on cps.RowID = cpl.RowID and cps.CustomPollerAssignmentID = cpl.CustomPollerAssignmentID where custompollerassignmentid in (SELECT CustomPollerAssignmentID FROM Orion.NPM.CustomPollerAssignment where assignmentname like 'VpnTunnels on%') and cpl.Label like '"+x+"%' and tolocal(DateTime) >= Addhour(-6, getdate())) tbl join orion.npm.CustomPollerAssignment cpa on tbl.custompollerassignmentid = cpa.custompollerassignmentid group by tbl.datetime, cpa.assignmentname"
        var params_vpn = JSON.stringify(
        {
        query: swql_vpn,
        parameters: {
        }
        });
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
         type: 'line',
         });
        myChart.destroy();
         
        
        
        /*Create the AJAX POST request*/
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Orion/Services/Information.asmx/Query',
        data: params_vpn,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) 
        {
     
            /*create an array from the response*/
            var obj = JSON.parse (JSON.stringify(response));
                var orig_data =[];
                for (var i=0; i<obj.d.Rows.length;i++)
                {
                orig_data.push.apply(orig_data,((obj.d.Rows[i])));
                }
            console.log(orig_data)
     
            /*converting time - unix format to normal format*/
            var date_index
                for ( date_index=0; date_index<orig_data.length; date_index=date_index+3)
                    {
                            var StartDateServer=orig_data[date_index]
                            var parsedDate = new Date(parseInt(StartDateServer.substr(6)));
                            var final_date = parsedDate.toUTCString() 
                            orig_data[date_index] = final_date 
                                        
                    }
     
            console.log(orig_data)
            /*slice the big array as multiple 3 element arrays*/
            var index = 0;
            var arrayLength = orig_data.length;
                 var arr = [];
         
            for (index = 0; index < arrayLength; index += 3) {
             myChunk = orig_data.slice(index, index+3);
             arr.push(myChunk);
         }
         console.log(arr)
        obj = {};
        arr.forEach(v => (obj[v[2]] || (obj[v[2]] = [])).push(v));
        var res = Object.keys(obj).map(v => obj[v]);
     
        console.log(res);
        /*start charting*/
        var bdcolor=["rgba(19, 15, 64,1.0)", "rgba(235, 77, 75,1.0)", "rgba(83, 92, 104,1.0)","rgba(44, 44, 84,1.0)","rgba(44, 58, 71,1.0)","rgba(109, 33, 79,1.0)","rgba(18, 137, 167,1.0)","rgba(0, 148, 50,1.0)","rgba(231, 76, 60,1.0)","rgba(243, 156, 18,1.0)","rgba(211, 84, 0,1.0)","rgba(192, 57, 43,1.0)","rgba(127, 140, 141,1.0)"];
     
     
     
     var chartdata = [];
     for (var i=0; i<res.length; i++)
     {
     
        var chartx=[]
        var charty=[]
        var chartl=[]
        
        for (var j=0;j<res[i].length;j++)
        {
            chartx.push(res[i][j][0]);
            charty.push(res[i][j][1]);
            chartl = x + " " + res[i][j][2];;
        }
     
        chartdata.push
        (
        {
     
                label: chartl,
                 data: charty,
                 lineTension:0.5,
                 fill:false,
                 borderColor:bdcolor[i],
                 borderWidth: 1
     
        }
            )
        }
     
     console.log(chartdata)
     
     
     
     myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
         type: 'line',
         data: {
             labels: chartx,
             datasets:chartdata 
         },
         options: {
            legend: {
                                 display: false,
                                 position: 'top',
                                 align: 'start'
     
     
                             },
             scales: {
                 yAxes: [{
                     ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                     }
                 }]
             
     
     
             }
         }
     });
     
     }
     
     
            
     
            
        },);
     
     }
     
     
     
     
     
  </script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chart Js , loading data on selection but bar graph displaying old values as well on hovering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61573166/chart-js-loading-data-on-selection-but-bar-graph-displaying-old-values-as-well)

Comment: i tried that earlier. it still switches back to the old chart. in fact, i tried many of the suggestions given earlier but nothing seem to be helping.

Comment: i added the below code just before drawing the chart. it always prints "empty chartdata". but when i hover my mouse on the graph, it shows old charts.. its puzzling .....  if (myChart) {
 console.log ("non-empty chartdata");
 }
 else{
  console.log("empty chartdata");
 }

Comment: Can you possibly provide a running `StackBlitz` that also contains your latest changes? This will make it much easier to propose a solution to your problem.

Comment: here is the code. when you choose prov, the line will be on 0. then when you choose lav, the line will be on 4. now if you hover the mouse on 0 line, it will show prov line.  The if condition on line 81 always says empty no matter if its first time or 2nd time.
   https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-rqtils?file=index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to define `var myChart` outside of the function `getoptiontunnels()`.

```
var myChart;
function getoptiontunnels() {
  ...
```

Then, inside the function `getoptiontunnels()`, you create the chart if it does not exist or you update its `data` if it already exists.

```
if (myChart) {
  myChart.data.labels = chartx;
  myChart.data.datasets = chartdata;
  myChart.update();
} else {
  myChart = new Chart('myChart', {
    ...     
  });
}
```

Please take a look at your amended code and see how it works.

```js
var myChart;
function getoptiontunnels() {

  var cust_tag = document.getElementById('Choosecustomer');
  var cust = cust_tag.value;
  var arr = []

  var obj = {};
  var data1 = [
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:38:49 GMT", 4, "device.ams1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:43:49 GMT", 4, "device.ams1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:48:49 GMT", 4, "device.ams1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:53:49 GMT", 4, "device.ams1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:58:49 GMT", 4, "device.ams1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 11:03:50 GMT", 4, "device.ams1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 11:08:50 GMT", 4, "device.ams1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 11:13:50 GMT", 4, "device.ams1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 11:18:50 GMT", 4, "device.ams1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 11:23:50 GMT", 4, "device.ams1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 11:28:50 GMT", 4, "device.ams1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 11:33:51 GMT", 4, "device.ams1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:39:15 GMT", 4, "device.blr1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:44:14 GMT", 4, "device.blr1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:49:12 GMT", 4, "device.blr1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:54:12 GMT", 4, "device.blr1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:59:13 GMT", 4, "device.blr1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 11:04:13 GMT", 4, "device.blr1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 11:09:13 GMT", 4, "device.blr1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 11:14:11 GMT", 4, "device.blr1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 11:19:12 GMT", 4, "device.blr1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 11:24:11 GMT", 4, "device.blr1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 11:29:11 GMT", 4, "device.blr1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 11:34:11 GMT", 4, "device.blr1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:38:45 GMT", 4, "device.ewr1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:43:46 GMT", 4, "device.ewr1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:48:46 GMT", 4, "device.ewr1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:53:46 GMT", 4, "device.ewr1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:58:46 GMT", 4, "device.ewr1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 11:03:46 GMT", 4, "device.ewr1"]
  ];

  var data2 = [
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:38:49 GMT", 0, "device.ams1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:43:49 GMT", 0, "device.ams1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:48:49 GMT", 0, "device.ams1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:53:49 GMT", 0, "device.ams1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:58:49 GMT", 0, "device.ams1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 11:03:50 GMT", 0, "device.ams1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 11:08:50 GMT", 0, "device.ams1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 11:13:50 GMT", 0, "device.ams1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 11:18:50 GMT", 0, "device.ams1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 11:23:50 GMT", 0, "device.ams1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 11:28:50 GMT", 0, "device.ams1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 11:33:51 GMT", 0, "device.ams1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:39:15 GMT", 0, "device.blr1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:44:14 GMT", 0, "device.blr1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:49:12 GMT", 0, "device.blr1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:54:12 GMT", 0, "device.blr1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:59:13 GMT", 0, "device.blr1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 11:04:13 GMT", 0, "device.blr1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 11:09:13 GMT", 0, "device.blr1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 11:14:11 GMT", 0, "device.blr1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 11:19:12 GMT", 0, "device.blr1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 11:24:11 GMT", 0, "device.blr1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 11:29:11 GMT", 0, "device.blr1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 11:34:11 GMT", 0, "device.blr1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:38:45 GMT", 0, "device.ewr1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:43:46 GMT", 0, "device.ewr1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:48:46 GMT", 0, "device.ewr1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:53:46 GMT", 0, "device.ewr1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:58:46 GMT", 0, "device.ewr1"],
    ["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 11:03:46 GMT", 0, "device.ewr1"]
  ];

  if (cust == "lav") {
    arr = data1;
  } else {
    arr = data2;
  }

  arr.forEach(v => (obj[v[2]] || (obj[v[2]] = [])).push(v));
  var res = Object.keys(obj).map(v => obj[v]);

  var bdcolor = ["rgba(26, 188, 156,1.0)", "rgba(46, 204, 113,1.0)", "rgba(52, 152, 219,1.0)", "rgba(52, 73, 94,1.0)", "rgba(22, 160, 133,1.0)", "rgba(41, 128, 185,1.0)", "rgba(241, 196, 15,1.0)", "rgba(230, 126, 34,1.0)", "rgba(231, 76, 60,1.0)", "rgba(243, 156, 18,1.0)", "rgba(211, 84, 0,1.0)", "rgba(192, 57, 43,1.0)", "rgba(127, 140, 141,1.0)"];

  var chartdata = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {

    var chartx = []
    var charty = []
    var chartl = []

    for (var j = 0; j < res[i].length; j++) {
      chartx.push(res[i][j][0]);
      charty.push(res[i][j][1]);
      chartl = cust + " " + res[i][j][2];;
    }

    chartdata.push({
      label: chartl,
      data: charty,
      lineTension: 0.5,
      fill: false,
      borderColor: bdcolor[i],
      borderWidth: 1
    })
  }
  
  if (myChart) {
    myChart.data.labels = chartx;
    myChart.data.datasets = chartdata;
    myChart.update();
  } else {
    myChart = new Chart('myChart', {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: chartx,
        datasets: chartdata
      },
      options: {
        legend: {
          display: true,
          position: 'left'
        },
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
getoptiontunnels();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<select id="Choosecustomer" onchange="getoptiontunnels();">
  <option value="lav">lav</option>
  <option value="prov">prov</option>
</select>
<br>
<canvas id="myChart" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: i am not sure how but this just worked perfectly.. i did read about this in the past in some other thread and i tried addding the var outside the function but i dont know.. ill have to go back and see where i was missing. but thanks a lot for spending ur valuable time for me.

Comment: Reading the following page may help you understandwhat's going on: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp&ved=2ahUKEwiWscz-47ntAhVDzqQKHQ63CPMQFjACegQIGRAB&usg=AOvVaw1CWxHkPy7Z5u0Pe0OuWUd6&cshid=1607272445726