# update chartJS if exists

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I would like to create a line chart with chartJS if it is not exists. If it exists, the existing should be updated. The `<canvas id="myChart" ></canvas>` is existing in any case.

Getting error:
*Uncaught TypeError: my_Chart.data is undefined*

How to update correctly?

Edit: Found a solution for check for existence of the chart [here][1].

```js
            let my_Chart = document.getElementById('myChart');
            let ctx = my_Chart.getContext('2d');

            // Check if a chart instance already exists
           if (!isCanvasBlank(my_Chart) ) {
                // If a chart instance exists, update its data and options
                alert('chart exists');
                my_Chart.data.datasets = chart_datasets;
                my_Chart.update();
            } else {
                // If a chart instance does not exist, create a new chart
                alert('chart doesn´t exists' );
                my_Chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: {
                        datasets: chart_datasets
                    },
                    options: {
                        scales: {
                            x: {
                                type: 'time',
                                time: {
                                    unit: 'day',
                                    unitStepSize: 1,
                                    displayFormats: {
                                        'day': 'dd. MMM'
                                    },
                                    tooltipFormat: 'dd. MMMM',
                                }
                            },
                            y: {
                                ticks: {
                                    beginAtZero: true
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        function isCanvasBlank(canvas) {
            return !canvas.getContext('2d')
                .getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data
                .some(channel => channel !== 0);
            }

[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17386803/15307393
```

Comment: There is a lot of confusion in your code - you are assigning to  the variable `my_Chart`  declared as (`const my_Chart`) - the error you should get is `"TypeError: Assignment to constant variable"`. At the same time, you are checking  `window.myChart` which is never assigned. So correct your typos, choose either `my_Chart` or `myChart` and then choose how you define that variable, either as `let myChart` or `window.myChart` - variables declared with `let` or `const` in the global scope are not set as properties of `window`, as it were the case with global variables declared with `var`.

Comment: @kikon I found a solution. Any suggestions for improvment?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```js
        let my_Chart = document.getElementById('myChart');
        let ctx = my_Chart.getContext('2d');

        // Check if a chart instance already exists
        if (my_Chart.chart_instance) {
            // If a chart instance exists, update its data and options
            if (!isCanvasBlank(my_Chart)) {
                // If the canvas is not blank, update the existing chart with new data
                my_Chart.chart_instance.data.datasets = chart_datasets;
                my_Chart.chart_instance.update();
            }
        } else {
            // If a chart instance does not exist, create a new chart
            my_Chart.chart_instance = new Chart(ctx, {
                // chart definition here
            });
        }
    }

    // Function to check if the canvas element is blank
    function isCanvasBlank(canvas) {
        return !canvas.getContext('2d')
            .getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data
            .some(channel => channel !== 0);
    }
```

any suggestions for improvement?

Comment: I don't see the reason for the inner `if` and  the test for canvas data. The test `if(my_Chart.chart_instance)` should be sufficient to determine that the instance should be updated.

Comment: You don't have to bother about the `canvas`, Chart.js finds it itself if you provide its `id` when creating the chart. Therefore, simply assign the chart to a variable and check that variable later on: `let chart = new Chart('myChart', {...});` ->  `if (chart) {`.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61574307/2358409